# Representation of rational numbers as the sum of 1/k

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is it true that every positive rational number $r = \frac{n}{m}$ could be represented as sum of $\frac{1}{k}$ for different $k$'s:

$$
r = \sum_{i=1}^{s} \frac{1}{c_i}
$$
where all $c_i$ are different?

If true, are there any bounds on number of summands $s$ based on $n$ and $m$?

Comment: google for "egyptian fractions".

Comment: It's a nice exercise to prove this for yourself.  In fact (hint), you can show that the *greedy algorithm* always works here: at each stage, choose $\frac{1}{c_i}$ to be as large as possible so that the partial sum is less than or equal to $r$.  

Comment: yes, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction has a complete exposition of the problem.

Comment: I think that the question about bounds on $s$ is still meaningful, but the reference Vose (1985) in the WP article seems to address it. 

Comment: There are currently some votes to close.  The commenters have mentioned the existence of a wikipedia article which at least addresses all of the OP's questions.  If the OP has further or more specific questions which are not completely answered by that article, it would be a good idea to edit the question accordingly before it gets closed.  

Comment: I don't think the Wikipedia article addresses the second question, at any rate if it's rephrased this way; given $s$, what are the smallest integers $m$ and $n$ such that $m/n$ requires $s$ summands? I think that question has only been answered for a few, small values of $s$, and OP might like to see references to such results. 

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I think we should close the question.

Comment: The question has been closed following (for my part, at least) the request of the OP.