# What's the simplest rational not expressible as a sum of a given number of unit fractions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, unit-fractions

This is essentially the same as the closed question [Representation of rational numbers as the sum of 1/k](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32956/representation-of-rational-numbers-as-the-sum-of-1-k) but I hope I can make a case for it as an MO-worthy question.

Ed Pegg, Jr., in his Math Games column for 19 July 2004 at the MAA website, http://www.maa.org/editorial/mathgames/mathgames_07_19_04.html writes, "Here is an interesting sequence of fractions that would likely would [sic] have fascinated Ahmes: $$1/2, 2/3, 4/5, 8/11, 14/17, 19/23, 24/29, 49/59, 65/71, 76/83, 61/157, 183/191, 260/269, 289/299.$$ $8/11 = 1/2 + 1/6 + 1/21 + 1/77$. This is the simplest Egyptian fraction that requires 4 parts. 
$14/17 = 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/20 + 1/55 + 1/187$ requires 5 parts. 289/299 is the simplest fraction that requires 14 parts. One might think that this sort of thing was well known, but it isn't.... What is the simplest fraction that requires 15 parts, 16 parts, and beyond?"

Pegg never defines "simplest," but presumably it means smallest (positive) denominator and, among fractions with the same denominator, smallest (positive) numerator. So the general question would be, given $s$, what's the simplest rational that can be expressed as a sum of $s$ unit fractions, but not fewer?

In this form, it's probably an open, and maybe impossible, problem (that is, I don't think anyone will find a simple formula for the rational as a function of $s$), so let me ask a bit less. Has there been any advance beyond 14 since 2004? Are there any bounds in the literature (that is, bounds on the "complexity" of the rational as a function of $s$)?

I note that Pegg gives no source for his list of 14. The Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences does not recognize the sequence of numerators, nor the sequence of denominators. Before anyone suggests typing "Egyptian fractions" into Google, or looking at the Wikipedia article on that subject, I hope he or she will verify that the particular question I'm asking is in fact answerable by such means.

EDIT: As per the comments, it appears that only the first four terms in Pegg's list are correct, and that the current state of knowledge is $${1\over2},{2\over3},{4\over5},{8\over11},{16\over17},{77\over79},{732\over733}.$$

Also as per the comments, if we are after
$f(s)=\min\lbrace b:N(a,b)=s{\rm\ for\ some\ }a,1\le a\lt b\rbrace$ then 
$f(s)\ge e^{Cn^2}$ for some $C>0$, and, conjecturally, $f(s)\ge e^{e^{Cn}}$ for some $C>0$.

At this point I will gladly settle for a calculation of $s(8)$.

Comment: Gerry, the wikipedia link to the Erdős–Straus conjecture (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Straus_conjecture) and the related conjecture due to Wacław Sierpiński, as well as the links there can be of help...

Comment: Is it obvious / known that for any n there is a rational number that can be written as a sum of n unit fraction, but not of n-1? If so, the proof might give you an upper bound on the numbers you are studying.

A bound in the other direction is provided by the result of Vose (1985) mentioned on the Wikipedia page, that there is an expansion of length $O(\sqrt{\log n})$ for a fraction with denominator n. At first glance, I did not find mention of a lower bound (a function f(n) such that $\sqrt{\log n}$ cannot be replaced by $f(n)$). One should study the literature - perhaps starting with Erdős.

Comment: I think you must additionally require `$r < 1$`, else the denominators will all be 2 (or 1).

Comment: @Wadim, Erdos-Straus conjecture if the numerator is 4 then $s=3$; Sierpinski is of a similar nature. I don't see how to use these conjectures to get even a conjecture as to how big the denominator has to be to enable $s=15$, say. @Lasse, yes, it is known that there are rationals with $s$ arbitrarily large. My first impression was that the proof I saw gave ludicrous bounds, but I really should take a closer look. I did look at the Vose paper, but maybe I didn't look closely enough. @Hugo, I'm not sure what your $r$ is, but I should have stated explicitly that I want 0 < numerator < denominator.

Comment: 14/17 = 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/14 + 1/476 appears to be an error; I believe 16/17 = 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/10 + 1/128 + 1/32640 is the simplest requiring 5 terms.

Comment: Gerry, I refer to the references there rather than to the link itself. For example, from MR0043117: "For given integral $a$, $b$ with $1\leq a<b$ let $N(a,b)$ denote the smallest integer $n$ such that $$ a/b=\sum_{r=1}^n1/x_r,\quad\text{with}\quad x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n, $$ is soluble in positive integers $x_r$. Sharpening a result and the method of N. G. de Bruijn he proves that $$ N(a,b)=O(\log b/\log\text{}\log b). $$ "

Comment: "He conjectures that the true result is $N(a,b)=O(\log\text{}\log b)$, and he in fact establishes the inequalities $$ \sum_{a=1}^{b-2}N(a,b)>{\textstyle\frac 1{2}}(b-2)(\log\text{}\log b-1),\quad N(b-1,b)>\log\text{}\log b-1. $$ "

Comment: @Hugo, interesting - I guess I shouldn't trust the other terms Pegg gives. @Wadim, if that conjecture is true, then $N(a,b)<C\log\log b$ for some constant $C$, while averaging on $a$, $N(a,b)>.5\log\log b$. The upper bound seems odd, in view of Pegg's assertion that $N(289,299)=14$. Well, I guess $C$ could be large. 

Comment: Ah thanks, Wadim, I couldn't find the paper of Erdos mentioned in the Vose paper, but maybe the title was wrong; anyway this seems to be exactly what is asked for.

So the case of b-1/b shows that the denominator of the smallest example for n grows at most like exp(exp(n)), and Erdos's conjecture states that it should grow at least like exp(exp(C*n)). Vose's result means it must grow at least like exp(C*n^2). So the "small" examples for $n\leq 14$ might be misleading.

Comment: Gerry and Lasse, I indeed think that small $s$ (or $N$) consideration is very misleading, as it's usual in arithmetic. I have no idea on whether Erdos's "guess" about $\log\log b$ is correct, but he had a very good intuition about such things...

Comment: I haven't checked the intervening numbers, but by hand I found 289/299 = 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/8 + 1/156 + 1/552. I checked also just using the greedy algorithm, and that gives 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/8 + 1/122 + 1/39795 + 1/1935522680. So I have no idea what Pegg's numbers are supposed to represent, but I can't see any relation between them and the stated problem.

Time permitting I'll try calculating the sequence, but I anticipate the correct denominators will grow much more rapidly, so it'll be hard to calculate more than 7-8 terms.

Comment: My apologies to all for taking Pegg's numbers on faith. Guy, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory, D11, writes, "Victor Meally...noted that 2/3, 4/5 and 8/11 are the [simplest rationals] that need 2, 3 and 4 [unit fractions].... Stephane Vandemergel, in a 93-04-28 letter, states that 16/17 requires 5 [unit] fractions, and 77/79 needs 6." With these numbers, I found  http://oeis.org/A097048 which gives 732/733 as the next, and last known, term. So unless there has been some advance since then, exact values are only known to $s=7$. As for bounds... (see next comment)

Comment: As for bounds, if someone wants to write up the information already contained in the previous comments as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it. 

Comment: Gerry, may I suggest that you add all this info to your question (without asking somebody to do a separate answer) and ask for $s>7$?

Comment: @Wadim, done. Thanks to everyone who has contributed comments. 

Comment: Lasse: re: "Is it obvious / known that for any n there is a rational number that can be written as a sum of n unit fraction, but not of n-1?" Maybe not obvious, but it is known. If s_i is the i'th number in Sylvester's sequence then (s_i-1)/s_i requires i terms. E.g. 1/2 requires 1 term, 2/3 requires 2, 6/7 requires 3, 42/43 requires 4, etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$s(8) = \frac{27538}{27539}$.

I have made the code I used available at http://crypt.org/hv/maths/least_eg-0.01.tar.gz, with a README file at http://crypt.org/hv/maths/least_eg-0.01-README.

Update: those links no longer available, code is available via github at https://github.com/hvds/seq/tree/master/least_eg.

The package includes both PARI/GP code and C code using the GNU GMP library to calculate the results, as well as a synopsis of the results for each denominator from 2 to 27539 which may be of use for further analysis.

I estimate the PARI code would have taken about a CPU-year to find the result; the C code runs over 20 times faster on my machine, and I don't understand why the difference is so great. (I'd appreciate email if someone can explain.)

Comment: Bravo. Bravissimo. Well done, and many thanks. 

Comment: The links are broken (2019). Can the files kindly be made available again?

Comment: Sorry I no longer have the original tarball; the C code available via github under https://github.com/hvds/seq/tree/master/least_eg should be the same or close to what was there.