# Minimum number of unit fractions to sum up a given positive rational

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms

For any positive $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$ there is a finite subset $S$ of $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq 1\}$ such that $\sum_{s\in S} s=\frac{p}{q}$, see [this article](https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1963-18.pdf) by Paul Erdös and Sherman Stein *(Sums of distinct unit fractions. Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, 14(1), 126-131, 1963.)* . Let $m(p,q)$ denote the minimal cardinality of such a subset $S$. Is there a polynomial-time algorithm to determine $m(p,q)$?

Comment: Distantly related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33628/whats-the-simplest-rational-not-expressible-as-a-sum-of-a-given-number-of-unit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, this is listed as an open problem in the [Wikipedia page on Egyptian Fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction), presumably because they do use the output size as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

No such polynomial-time algorithm exists because in some instances it would take too long to write down (or store in memory) the answer. In particular, if $n$ is a positive integer, then we have $\sum_{k=1}^{m(n,1)} \frac{1}{k} \geq n$, which implies that $m(n,1) \geq \frac{1}{5} e^{n}$. In such an instance, the number of input bits is about $\log_{2}(n)$ and the number of output bits is around $n$.

Comment: What about polynomial in the size of the output?

Comment: The question is still quite subtle for fractions between 0 and 1. In this case, $m(p,q)$ is quite small ($O(\sqrt{\log(q)})$), but determining the precise value is probably quite hard (as hard as factoring in some cases probably).